# How to read multi-line column value from hive table? Columns having new line characters and space

Tags: sql, hive

I have following Hive table so when i run select query on col3 it will return result like..

```
col3
opt-91092019
nullopt-287211
```

so null  is append to the column value and at the end 2 spaces are there.
so I want output as

```
col3
opt-91092019
opt-287211
```

without any extra character.

```
|------+------+--------+------------------+-------+------|
|row1: | col1 | col2   | col3(multi-line) | col4  | col5 |
|------+------+--------+------------------+-------+------|
|      |      |        | opt-91092019     |       |      |
|row2: | A    | S      | opt-287211       | abcd  | hft  |
|      |      |        | opt-7123872      |       |      |
|------+------+--------+------------------+-------+------|
|row3: | B    | R      | opt-26725rfe     | pore  | hft2 |
|------+------+--------+------------------+-------+------|
|row4: | C    | Q      | single-line1     | ertfd | hft3 |
|------+------+--------+------------------+-------+------|
|row5: | D | P | single-line2     | bcde4 | hft4 |
|------+------+--------+------------------+-------+------|
```

Comment: Fix the table structure so you don't have a multi-line value

Comment: I do not want to change raw data structure.